# How can I set a generic type in Blazored.LocalStorage?

Tags: local-storage, blazor

I am using Blazored.LocalStorage nuget package in Blazor.
I want to change List < CartItem > to Generic type.
How can I do?

```
public async Task AddToCart(CartItem cartItem)
        {
            var cart = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<CartItem>>("cart");
            if(cart == null)
                cart = new List<CartItem>();
            cart.Add(cartItem);

            await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("cart", cart);

            OnChange.Invoke();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public async Task AddItem<T>(string listName, T item)
{
    List<T> list = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<T>>(listName);
  
    if(list is null)
        list = new();

    list.Add(item);

    await _localStorage.SetItemAsync(listName, list);

    OnChange.Invoke();
}
```